# Foreign Key Constraint Failed on Index Field Prisma Delete

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to delete all items from a table using postgres + prisma

I have the following schema:

```
model Profile {
  id String @id @default(cuid())
  projects Project[]
}

model Project {
  id String @id @default(cuid())

  profile Profile @relation(fields: [profile_email], references: [email], onDelete: NoAction)
  profile_email String
}
```

Here's the code with the client:

```js
const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client");

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

(async () => {
  await prisma.profile.deleteMany({});

  await prisma.project.deleteMany({});
})();
```

The error I get is this -

```
Invalid `prisma.profile.deleteMany()` invocation in
clear.js:6:24

  3 const prisma = new PrismaClient();
  4 
  5 (async () => {
→ 6   await prisma.profile.deleteMany(
  Foreign key constraint failed on the field: `Project_profile_email_fkey (index)`
```

How can we solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

When you try to delete a profile, there might be projects with a foreign key that references a profile. Because of this relation, you will get an error when trying to delete a profile. You can use referential actions. In your case, replace "OnDelete: NoAction with OnDelete: Cascade" inside the relation field in the Project model. (EDIT: Make sure to update your database as well with the new constraint)

You can read more about it here:
[Referential actions | Prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/referential-actions)

Comment: In the case where you need to retain the record of the project even though the profile is deleted replace `onDelete: Cascade` with `onDelete: SetNull`, in which case `profile` and `profile_attributes` would need to be optional fields in the Project model.

Answer (score 0):

You use "profile" and "project", instead use "Profile" and "Project" with first letter uppercase, or use @@map for change the name of your model. (The models are crated with same name from model or the name you set in @@map)

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#introspection-and-migration